# What am i getting wrong in trying to insert record into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\Program >Files\Ampps\www\ATTENDANCE\db\crud.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program >Files\Ampps\www\ATTENDANCE\success.php(14): crud->insertAttendees('Aliyu', 'Adeniji', >'10/10/1990', 'adenijialiuadey...', '08144959368', '1') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program >Files\Ampps\www\ATTENDANCE\db\crud.php on line 15

crude.php

```
<?php 

class crud{
  private $db;

  function __construct($conn){
    $this-> $db=$conn;
  }

  public function insertAttendees($fname, $lname,$email,$dob,$phone,$specialty){
        try {
            // define sql statement to be executed
            $sql = "INSERT INTO attendee (firstname,lastname,email,dob,phone,specialty_id) VALUES (:fname,:lname,:dob,:email,:phone,:specialty)";
            //prepare the sql statement for execution
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            // bind all placeholders to the actual values
            $stmt->bindparam(':fname',$fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(':lname',$lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(':dob',$dob);
            $stmt->bindparam(':email',$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(':phone',$phone);
            $stmt->bindparam(':specialty',$specialty);
  
            // execute statement
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Your email and date of birth are swapped. Make sure that the columns and values align.

Comment: I have  tried that  already but it is not working.

Comment: Is there a new error message after fixing the column/value order?

Comment: same error message

Comment: Not sure what the error could be at the database. You might want to try capturing the SQL statement as it lands in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html  It might be something to do with data not fitting the column data type, but who knows.

Comment: Also take a look at this article. I haven't worked with PHP, but you might be doing something wrong. https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/php-prepared-statement/#:~:text=Introduction%20to%20PHP%20prepared%20statements%20A%20prepared%20statement,and%20helps%20protect%20the%20application%20against%20SQL%20injections.